Symbolic differentiation Gamma function (rings - algebra)
I was after an expression for the the nth derivative of the Gamma function and I managed to find this
Symbolic differentiation Gamma
which reads as
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^{(n)}(z) = \Gamma(z) R(n,z)
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
R(n,z) = \psi(z)R(n-1,z)+R^{(0,1)}(n-1,z)\;\wedge\; R(0,z) = 1
\end{equation}
where $\psi$ is the digamma function. However, there is not much an explanation about $R(\cdot,\cdot)$, except for being defined recursively. I suspect it some sort of ring in two variables (but I'm not an algebra expert). It is even less clear to me what $R^{(0,1)}(\cdot,\cdot)$ stands for.
Not knowing what $R$ and $R^{(0,1)}$ are, I tried to figure it out by explicitly computing the first 4 derivatives of the $\Gamma$ function. These are (I removed the dependence on $z$)
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\Gamma' &= \Gamma \psi\\
\Gamma'' &= \Gamma\left(\psi^2+\psi'\right)\\
\Gamma'''& = \Gamma \left(\psi^3+3\psi\psi' +\psi''\right)\\
\Gamma^{(4)} &= \Gamma\left(\psi^4 + 6\psi^2\psi' + 4\psi \psi'' + 3 (\psi')^2+\psi'''\right)
\end{split}\end{equation}
Then I used the recursive definition to match the values of $R$ and $R^{(0,1)}$. These should be
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
R(0,z)&=1\\
R(1,z) &= \psi R(0,z) + R^{(0,1)}(0,z) \\
&= \psi + R^{(0,1)}(0,z) \; \Rightarrow \;R^{(0,1)}(0,z) = 0 \\
R(2,z) &=\psi R(1,z) + R^{(0,1)}(1,z) \\
&= \psi^2 + R^{(0,1)}(1,z) \;\Rightarrow \; R^{(0,1)}(1,z) = \psi'\\
R(3,z) &=\psi R(2,z) + R^{(0,1)}(2,z) \\
&= \psi (\psi^2 +\psi') + R^{(0,1)}(2,z) \;\Rightarrow \; R^{(0,1)}(2,z) = 2\psi\psi' +\psi''\\
R(4,z) &=\psi R(3,z) + R^{(0,1)}(3,z) \\
&= \psi (\psi^3 +3\psi\psi' +\psi'') + R^{(0,1)}(3,z) \;\Rightarrow \; R^{(0,1)}(3,z) = 3(\psi^2\psi' +\psi\psi''+ (\psi')^2)+\psi'''\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I see there is a "pattern" but I can't figure it out myself.   Is there a formal definition for $R^{(0,1)}(n,z)$?
Thank you!

If you click the formula, you get to a page with explanation and a Wolfram Language input for the formula. In fact the notation is for $\frac{\partial R(n-1,z)}{\partial z}$ (look for Derivative[0,1][R][n - 1, z]).

Thank you. I figured it out.

I would still appreciate some insight on the algebraic aspect of the problem. Are all the functions $R(n, z)$ elements of a ring (or any other algebraic structure)? What about   $R^{(0,1)}(n, z)$? Thanks
